# Want to use sqlite3.h in iOS application

Tags: objective-c, swift, sqlite

I am responsible for converting an application from Objective-C to Swift. One of the objective c files called 'database' imports file called sqlite3.h. Now I did not convert database.h and database.m to Swift. Instead I created an Objective-C bridging header that exposed the database code to the Swift files. However the database header file imports a file called sqlite3.h. So first I linked a library to my project called libsqlite3.dylib as I believed this library contains the sqlite3.h file. But I cannot view any header files the library contains.

So do I just need to include the libsqlite3.dylib in my objective-c bridging header file, and if so whats the syntax? Or do i need to download the sqlite3.h header file, and if so where can I get the code from or download it from?

Comment: Add the exact error you are getting when you build to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries do not contain header files (i.e. there is no header inside a dylib file).

In database.h (or .m), there is a line that looks like this:

```
#import <sqlite3.h>
```

Right-click on it and choose "Jump to definition" -- it should take you to the file.  If not, something is wrong with your header paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the sqlite3 using cocopods:

```
   pod 'sqlite3'
```

Or if you want the swift version:

```
   https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift
```